# How to make a Socket.IO instance available on different pages with React Router

Tags: reactjs, socket.io, react-router

I am trying to make a single page application that includes react, react-router, socket.io. I am using babel to compile es6 and jsx to plain js.

I want to make a socket instance available in many different components, on several different routes.

When the user connects, I must create a socket instance (I do this with 
`import io from 'socket.io-client'`, and then `const socket = io()`). I then want to be able to access this socket object from different components on different routes (of react router). I want to keep the same connection as the user moves between pages.

I currently have a hack that works. I put all my react components on the same page, and at the top of this page, I put `const socket = io()`, to create the socket instance. I can then use this global socket within all my components. I don't think this approach is very good though, because it requires having all the components in one file.

Can I define the socket in the state of the App component (the component that has the `<Router>`)? I could then pass it down as props to all the route components.

It seemed like contexts (https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html) could be useful, except that link mentions that I should not use it. I have also come across redux, but I have a feeling it's unnecessary complexity for what I want.

If there is anything I can add or clarify, please let me know. Thanks so much for any help!

Comment: If you don't want to opt into redux or other state management tools, context is the best way of doing what you want IMHO.